# Putting a connection string in the web config

Tags: c#

So I'm using C# and I've got the following SQL connection string:

```
private static string _conn = Properties.Settings.Default.dBizConnectionString;
```

And I'd like to know if and how I can put it in the web config and app config? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a blog post from Scott Forsyth explaining everything:

[Using Connection Strings from web.config](http://weblogs.asp.net/owscott/archive/2005/08/26/Using-connection-strings-from-web.config-in-ASP.NET-v2.0.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is yes, like so:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionStringName" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Server=ServerName; Initial Catalog=InitialCatalog; User ID=User; Password=Password; MultipleActiveResultSets=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

There's a lot of information out there about connection strings. There are more options you can specify, they can be encrypted, etc. etc., but this will get you started.

Answer (score 0):

Add it to the web config like this:

```
  <connectionStrings>
     <add name="myConnectionStringName" connectionString="Data Source=mySqlServerInstance;Initial Catalog=myCatalog;User ID=myUserId;Password=myPassword"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Add code to retrieve it:

```
private static string GetConnectionString()
{
    var config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("/myProject");
    var connections = config.ConnectionStrings;
    var settings = connections.ConnectionStrings["myConnectionStringname"];
    string connectionString = settings.ConnectionString;
    return connectionString;
}
```